# Is there a way to deselect date in Pikaday?

Tags: javascript, pikaday

Is there a way to deselect selected by user day in Pikaday calendar?

I would like to get from this state

[image]

to the following one

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the pickers date to null using `.setDate(null)` and attaching a listener to a button you press as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#get-and-set-date) to clear the selected date.